The parameters 'sources' for goal org.codehaus.mojo:build-helper-maven-plugin add-test-source are missing or invalid
My project has such a structure:
my-project/
     /src
       /api-test
            /java
              /tests
               /my
                 /project
                 /apiTests
                 /constants
                 /facades
                 TestsApiSuite.java
       /main
       /it-test

But when I run a Maven plugin "mvn clean build-helper:add-test-source verify -PapiTests" it displays me an error:  The parameters 'sources' for goal org.codehaus.mojo:build-helper-maven-plugin:3.2.0:add-test-source are missing or invalid -> [Help 1].
But sources are specified. My pom.xml looks like this:
https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.12</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.my.platform</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-project</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>my-project</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>

        <junit.jupiter.version>5.6.2</junit.jupiter.version>
        <plugin.versions.version>2.1</plugin.versions.version>
        <plugin.surefire.version>2.6</plugin.surefire.version>
        <plugin.failsafe.version>2.6</plugin.failsafe.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.undertow</groupId>
            <artifactId>undertow-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.12.Final</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>

            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>io.undertow</groupId>
                    <artifactId>undertow-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>io.undertow</groupId>
                    <artifactId>undertow-websockets-jsr</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/versions.txt</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/versions.txt</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/api-test/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>

        <profile>
            <id>apiTests</id>

            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
                    <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
                    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
                    <version>20080701</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-platform-runner</artifactId>
                    <version>1.7.0-M1</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
                    <version>1.7.0-M1</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
                    <artifactId>allure-junit5</artifactId>
                    <version>2.13.3</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-platform-suite-api</artifactId>
                    <version>1.7.0-M1</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-platform-commons</artifactId>
                    <version>1.7.0-M1</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>io.github.artsok</groupId>
                    <artifactId>rerunner-jupiter</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1.6</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
                    <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
                    <version>4.0.0</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>

            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
                        <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.5</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>addTestSources</goal>
                                    <goal>testCompile</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <source>11</source>
                            <target>11</target>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
                            <systemProperties>
                                <property>
                                    <name>junit.jupiter.extensions.autodetection.enabled</name>
                                    <value>true</value>
                                </property>
                            </systemProperties>
                        </configuration>
                        <dependencies>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                                <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                                <version>1.2.0</version>
                            </dependency>

                        </dependencies>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
                        <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
                        <version>2.8</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <reportVersion>2.4.1</reportVersion>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*TestAPISuite.java</include>
                            </includes>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>verify</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>verify</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>add-api-test-source-as-test-sources</id>
                                <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>add-test-source</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <sources>
                                        <source>${project.basedir}/src/api-test/java</source>
                                    </sources>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>



Ancient old spring Boot version... Also defining version of jackson on your own? No keep the ones provided by SB.. Why defining old plugin versions? (plugin.surfire.version) does not make sense.. ? Why using a profile with different dependencies which are not consistent... Use Junit Jupiter without defining versions on your own.. use the bom setup. Remove the junit-platform-surefire-provider... etc. Simply use naming conventions instead of different directories is easier...
